# How do I conduct an ANCOVA within a pre and posttest design?

Tags: experiment-design, ancova

I have a question regarding the analysis of my quasi field experiment. I conducted an experiment in a high school where a class learns over 5 weeks with a smart personal assistant (n=22) and the other class receive paper-based learning aids (n=23). I used a pre-posttest design. Now I ran an ANCOVA and checked its assumptions before (normality, homogeneity of variance and homogeneity of regression). I included the control variables gender, pre-experience with SPAs, school grades, personal innovativeness as independent variables and the pre-test as covariate. I first ran a regression to see if there were main effects of the control variables. School report is the only variable that has a significant influence on posttest results. nevertheless, I included all the control variables in the ANCOVA.

The ANCOVA with all the control variables and pre-test as covariate identified a significant effect (F (1, 43) = 21.50, r2 adjusted = 0.54, eta squared = x, p = 5.723e-06 , N = 45). Cohens d is 1.75.

And now my questions:
1. School grades variable: How do I deal with the control variable school grades? Do I have to include every control variable? Can I simply include school grade in my main ANCOVA?
3. Equality of two groups: since both groups are not randomly assigned, how can I make sure that they are equal? chi-square or ANOVA?
4. R2: Do I also have to report r squared and eta squared in my publication?
5. Different scales: I have different scales on posttest score and school grades. Is that a problem?
6. p-value: the resulting p-value from the anova is really small, 5.723e-06. Does that mean it it significant below 0.001? Moreover, the p-value from the ancova is different compared to the p-value from the regression model. Which one should be reported in the paper?

Thank you so much for answering the questions. You really help me a lot!

Comment: I think some things need clarification. What do you mean by "homogeneity of regression"? Also, with respect to "normality" and "homogeneity of variances" did you check this for the DV or for the residuals from the model? The answer should be the latter, especially in your case with many independent variables.

Comment: Models for such comparisons should be pre-specified before looking at the data, in order to do reproducible research.  Generally speaking, the largest model entertained is the one to fit.  Adjusting for the pre value is all important.

Comment: thanks for your answer. homogeneity of regression = when regressing pretest and posttest, both treatment groups should show similar slopes. I checked the normality and homogeneity of variances for the residuals. So would you include all control variables as independent variables in the ANCOVA and report the resulting p-value. What if school grades is also significant? How do I report that?